# How to create a background image in gtk + 3?

Tags: c, background, gtk

I am looking for a way to set a background image in gtk + 3 with c language , I already search and all the answer are for other languages or don't work anymore . Does anyone know  a proper way to do it ?

Comment: Well be more precise about your Question. What background are trying to set? The main window some widget?  Where is the code ?

Comment: I am trying to set a background image in a gtk window , like an image who take all the window size but that is behind all the other widget , and i didn't even find how to do it so there's no code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all problem encounter with the style in gtk i realize that using css for gtk wase the best answer , here some link that can be good to know

[Css + Gtk Overview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html)

[Gtk + Css Properties](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-properties.html)